# Adding a space to every character without creating a column with them VBScript

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to make a script which only adds spaces to the characters and doesn't create a column with them. This is the code i tried:

```
<%

a=Split("Example1, Example2, Example3",",")
for each x in a
    response.write(x & "<br />")
next

%>
```

And the problem is that i have a large text which only would create would be this (Which is the normal output):

- "Example1"
- "Example2"
- "Example3"

And what i want it to write is this:
"E x a m p l e 1 E x a m p l e 2 E x a m p l e 3"

I'm new to code here so i don't have any ideas to do. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need another loop to go through each string a character at a time and input a space.

Answer (score 2):

As Lankymart mentioned in the comments, you can loop through each character of your string and add a space. Here's a simple function that does that:

```
Function SpaceText(p_sText)
    Dim iCounter
    Dim sSpacedText
    
    sSpacedText = ""
    For iCounter = 1 To Len(p_sText)
        sSpacedText = sSpacedText & Mid(p_sText, iCounter, 1)
        If iCounter < Len(p_sText) Then sSpacedText = sSpacedText & " "
    Next

    SpaceText = sSpacedText

End Function
```

You can use this function inside your existing loop:

```
response.write(SpaceText(x) & "<br />")
```

Note that it doesn't add an extra space after the last letter so you need to factor that in when concatenating the values of your array.